# Update method not working correctly in the serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

Here is the code my code; I tried different solution, but none of them work. I also added function to add new question if the id is not here. I think it didn't see the id and I tried logging it. It says none;
I don't know why its not seeing my if, but when I do get method I get the id in response so I don't know what to do.

I hope I provided enough code for you.

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .Models.QuizMaker import QuizMake
from .Models.Answers import Answers
from .Models.Questions import Questions
import string, secrets


def generate_quiz_session_token():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    token = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(8))
    return token

class AnswersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answers
        fields = ['id','answer', 'is_correct']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswersSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ['id','question', 'description', 'image', 'answers']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    quiz_session_token = serializers.CharField(max_length=8, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = QuizMake
        fields = ['id','name', 'req_time', 'fk_teacher_id', 'quiz_session_token', 'questions']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
    def create(self,validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        quiz = QuizMake.objects.create(
            name = validated_data['name'],
            req_time = validated_data['req_time'],
            fk_teacher_id = validated_data['fk_teacher_id'],
            quiz_session_token = generate_quiz_session_token(),
        )
        for question_data in questions_data:
            answers_data = question_data.pop('answers')
            question = Questions.objects.create(fk_quiz_id=quiz, **question_data)
            for answer_data in answers_data:
                Answers.objects.create(fk_question_id=question, **answer_data)
        return quiz
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.req_time = validated_data.get('req_time', instance.req_time)
        instance.fk_teacher_id = validated_data.get('fk_teacher_id', instance.fk_teacher_id)
        instance.save()

        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        for question_data in questions_data:
            answers_data = question_data.pop('answers', [])
            question_id = question_data.get('id')
            if question_id:
                question = Questions.objects.get(pk=question_id)
                question.question = question_data.get('question', question.question)
                question.description = question_data.get('description', question.description)
                question.image = question_data.get('image', question.image)
                question.save()

                existing_answer_ids = [answer_data.get('id') for answer_data in answers_data if 'id' in answer_data]
                existing_answers = Answers.objects.filter(fk_question_id=question, id__in=existing_answer_ids)
                for existing_answer in existing_answers:
                    answer_data = next((item for item in answers_data if item.get('id') == existing_answer.id), None)
                    if answer_data:
                        existing_answer.answer = answer_data.get('answer', existing_answer.answer)
                        existing_answer.is_correct = answer_data.get('is_correct', existing_answer.is_correct)
                        existing_answer.save()

                new_answers = [answer_data for answer_data in answers_data if 'id' not in answer_data]
                for new_answer_data in new_answers:
                    Answers.objects.create(fk_question_id=question, **new_answer_data)
            else:
                question = Questions.objects.create(fk_quiz_id=instance, **question_data)
                for answer_data in answers_data:
                    Answers.objects.create(fk_question_id=question, **answer_data)

        return instance
```